# How can add a CSS class if a condition is met Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, haml, truncate

I'm working on creating a truncate directive and I have the string of text truncating if the characters exceed 10. It will then display the "...".

My Goal is to write a condition that removes the "..." if the characters are less than 10. Kind of stuck on this and open to suggestions if anyone has any ideas on how I could accomplish this.

Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Controller
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "John Doe Blah blah";
});

// Directive
app.directive('truncate', function() {
  function link(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.truncate = function(str){
      if(str.length > 10) {
        return 'truncate'
      } else{
        return 'notruncate'
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Write a condition to check if the username is < 10 characters to hide the ellipse
  
  
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        input: '=',
        maxCharacters: '=',
        href: '=',
        isShowMore: '='
      },
    template: '<h4 ng-init="limit=true;length=maxCharacters">{{input | limitTo: length}}<a ng-attr-href="#" ng-click="limit=!limit;length=limit?maxCharacters: \'\'">{{isShowMore?"Show More":"..."}}</a></h4>',
    link: link
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <body ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <div href='true' input='text' is-show-more='false' max-characters='10' truncate=''></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing without angular or javascript using the text-overflow: ellipsis property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive on the `span` element that contains '...', with the following condition:

```
ng-hide="input.length <= maxCharacters || !length"
```

that means that this element is going to be hidden in case the length of input is less or equals `maxCharacters` or filter is not applied.

Working example based on your codepen:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Controller
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "John Doe Blah blah";
});

// Directive
app.directive('truncate', function() {
    // Write a condition to check if the username is < 10 characters to hide the ellipse

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            input: '=',
            maxCharacters: '=',
            href: '=',
            isShowMore: '='
        },
        template: '<h4 ng-init="limit=true;length=maxCharacters">{{input | limitTo: length}}<a ng-attr-href="#" ng-click="limit=!limit;length=limit?maxCharacters: \'\'" ng-hide="input.length <= maxCharacters || !length" >{{isShowMore?"Show More":"..."}}</a></h4>'
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <body ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <div href='true' input='text' is-show-more='false' max-characters='10' truncate=''></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!   This is exactly what I needed. I understand the logic behind it as well

Comment: @ThomasBrushel you could accept the answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Hey, I have a quick question since you seemed very knowledgeable in Angular js. I'm trying to do the same thing here on this codepen https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/pWbzqM I've taken a little bit or a different approach. I have the truncate functionality built out, however, I can't get it to hide and show based on a set amount of characters. Also, I'm trying to figure out how to use %atom-heading{text: 'whatever'} without attaching truncatorBindings to the HTML tag. If you open up the console you can see that I'm getting an error saying that TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Angular has an ngClass directive that will apply a class based on the evaluated text of the expression. Just write a function that returns a different class depending on the string length and then call that in ngClass.

Docs for ngClass: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Example code snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Controller
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.text = "John Doe Blah blah";
      
      $scope.truncate = function(str){
        if (str.length > 10) {
         return 'truncate'
        } else {
         return 'notruncate'
        }
      }
});
```

```css
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.notruncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-class="truncate(text)" style="width: 40px">{{text}}</div>
</html>
```

Comment: That's why I'm stuck. I've only been working in AngularJs for the last two weeks lol. I already have the ellipse displaying. I just need something to say if there are less than 10 char make {{isShowMore?"Show More":"..."}} to not show more.

Comment: I modified my code. To test just change the value of `$scope.text`. It will do what you want and doesn't need the complicated boolean logic (or a custom directive). You do have to size the div correctly based on how much of the text you want truncated but that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thank you! I really like this solution and it would work if this wasn't for a large scale application. This needs to be a directive so it can be used in multiple places around the site.  I need to build it in a directive and then also buid it out in a component.

Comment: You can wrap this functionality in a directive. Just make the function and the ng-class stuff part of a wrapper directive. The class will be global because it's angular 1.x, but it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```js
"use strict";

function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.example = "Yeyuh im so long, where does it end?!";
}

function truncate() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      text: "=",
      length: "="
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var elm = $element[0];
      $scope.$watch("text", function(newText, oldText) {
        if (elm.classList.value.indexOf("notruncate") > -1) {
          elm.classList.remove("notruncate");
        }
        if (newText.length > $scope.length) {
          elm.className = "truncate";
        }
        if (newText.length < $scope.length) {
          if (elm.classList.value.indexOf("truncate") > -1) {
            elm.classList.remove("truncate");
          }
          elm.className = "notruncate";
        }
      });
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module("example", [])
  .controller("exampleController", exampleController)
  .directive("truncate", truncate);
```

```css
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.notruncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="example">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="example" truncate text="example" length="10">
  </div>
</div>
```