# How do components communicate with directives? (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

So I'm a little confused on how components communicate with directives. I know how to create components and I also know how to create directives. I need to create a truncate directive that communicates with a component.

Comment: elobarate on "I need to create a truncate directive that communicates with a component"...and please specify whether your question is specific to angularjs or angular 2

Comment: I'm basically taking what I did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184676/how-can-add-a-css-class-if-a-condition-is-met-angular-js/46185303?noredirect=1#comment79364718_46185303 and I'm just trying to make it a reusable component

Comment: What king of communication should happen? `directive` is already a re-usable thing, so you could try to add some example to your question to make it clear.